# Navbar which hides when you scroll down and appears again when you scroll up

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I have explored few approaches to this, but none really seems to work exactly like I would like:

- I would like that when scrolling down, navbar is moving up at the speed the user is scrolling down, like that is static at that point.
- When it disappears, I would like that the bottom of it is still visible, because this is where I have a progress bar (but maybe progress bar should detach at that point and be on top of the viewport).
- When you scroll up, I would like that navbar appears again, again at the speed of scrolling, like it is static, until you see the whole navbar, when it should stick to the top of the viewport.

Here is [an example](https://codepen.io/mitar/pen/zYpBJxP) of behavior I would like, but not performance/experience (because behavior is implemented using `scroll` event, it is not smooth).

I have also attempted to use CSS transform, which would on scroll down add a class to hide the navbar, and scroll up remove the class, animating the navbar hiding/showing, but the issue with that is that animation speed is disconnected with scrolling speed.

I tried CSS sticky position as well, but it looks like I need the opposite of what it provides.

Is there some other way to make this work well?

Answer (score 1):

Checking the link you provided, it seems to work as expected (*you want it to be linked to the scroll event since you want it to move as "static"*). If, though, it staggers on some system due to inconsistent scroll events, you could try adding a `transition` property with a small enough duration. Keep in mind the this should only be enabled while the position property remains the same, otherwise when changing from "absolute" to "fixed" it would mess things up, since the coordinate origin changes.

So you can  add another variable `let changedPosition = false;` and whenever you change the `position` property you can do

```
if (position !== "absolute") {
  changedPosition = true;
} else {
  changedPosition = false;
}
position = "absolute";
```

or

```
if (position !== "fixed") {
  changedPosition = true;
} else {
  changedPosition = false;
}
position = "fixed";
```

and when you apply the style do

```
navbar.style = `position: ${position}; top: ${navbarTop}px; transitiona: ${
    changedPosition ? "none" : "100ms linear"
  }`;
```

like https://codepen.io/gpetrioli/pen/XWVKxNG?editors=0010

---

You should play around a bit with the transition properties you provide, i just put some sample values there.

Comment: Yes, it works like expected, but it is not as smooth. I wonder if there is a way to achieve this without using JavaScript, just CSS. For example, when machine is under load, when I scroll it sometimes happens that the navbar comes all the way to the middle of the screen, before JS changes it to fixed position at the top.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at your problem and I think i found a simple approach.

with this simple function you can get the amount of pixels user has scrolled.

```
window.onscroll = function (e) {
    console.log(window.scrollY); // Value of scroll Y in px
};
```

after user scrolls the desired amount of pixels, make the progress bar `fixed top` ( or `position:fixed;top:0`)

Comment: Thank you! I think something like this is what I am already doing. But the problem is that movement is not smooth and navbar jumps around sometimes.

Comment: just add some animation when the navbar gets the desired class. also set scroll-behaviour:smooth on your body

Answer (score 0):

Gabriele Petrioli gave a great answer, but with a typo in the 'transitiona' word.
Here is a web-performance-oriented code with onScroll throttling and code improvements:

```
<script>
let throttling = false;

function onScrollThrottled() {
  if (!throttling) {
    throttling = true;
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      onScroll();
      throttling = false;
    });
  }
}


let navbarTop = 0;
let transition = true;
let position = "absolute";
let lastScrollPosition = 0;

const navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");

function onScroll() {

  const currentScrollPosition = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

  if (currentScrollPosition <= 0) {

    lastScrollPosition = 0;
    navbarTop = 0;

    if (position !== "absolute") { transition = true; }
    else { transition = false; }
    position = "absolute";

  } else {
    
    if (currentScrollPosition > lastScrollPosition) {

      if (position !== "absolute") { transition = true; }
      else { transition = false; }
      position = "absolute";

      let { top, height } = navbar.getBoundingClientRect()
      navbarTop = currentScrollPosition + Math.max(top, -height);

    } else {

      const { top } = navbar.getBoundingClientRect()

      if (top >= 0) {

        navbarTop = 0;

        if (position !== "fixed") { transition = true; }
        else { transition = false; }
        position = "fixed";

      }

    }

    lastScrollPosition = currentScrollPosition;

  }
  navbar.style = `position: ${position}; top: ${navbarTop}px; transition: ${ transition ? "none" : "100ms linear" }`;
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", onScrollThrottled, { passive: true });
</script>
```

And here is the minified coode:

```
let throttling=!1;function onScrollThrottled(){throttling||(throttling=!0,requestAnimationFrame((()=>{onScroll(),throttling=!1})))}let navbarTop=0,transition=!0,position="absolute",lastScrollPosition=0;const navbar=document.getElementById("navbar");function onScroll(){const t=window.pageYOffset||document.documentElement.scrollTop;if(t<=0)lastScrollPosition=0,navbarTop=0,transition="absolute"!==position,position="absolute";else{if(t>lastScrollPosition){transition="absolute"!==position,position="absolute";let{top:o,height:n}=navbar.getBoundingClientRect();navbarTop=t+Math.max(o,-n)}else{const{top:t}=navbar.getBoundingClientRect();t>=0&&(navbarTop=0,transition="fixed"!==position,position="fixed")}lastScrollPosition=t}navbar.style=`position: ${position}; top: ${navbarTop}px; transition: ${transition?"none":"100ms linear"}`}window.addEventListener("scroll",onScrollThrottled,{passive:!0});
```